# A generic/easy way to encapsulate properties of classes over a whole project

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Im currently designing a winforms app that needs to be able to output values of various properties in various classes to a serial/udp port.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to iterate over all of the instances of classes in this project at runtime, and then display to the user a select bunch (maybe by using attributes?) and their corresponding string value so they can output any combination of these values.

So, for (a simplified) example, say i have two classes:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public double Price{get;set;}
  public int Units{get;set}
  //other properties that I don't want visible to the user
}

public class ClassB
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Description{get;set;}
  //other properties not visible to the user
}
```

I will have many instances of these classes instantiated at runtime (and they may not necessarily be linked/referenced/related to each other).

e.g.

```
public ClassA Cars = new ClassA();
public ClassB Models = new ClassB();
public ClassA PCs = new ClassA();
//set properties of these instances
//etc.. more of these
```

I would like to gather all of these instances and show the corresponding fields to the user:

```
Cars.Price = "1000";
Cars.Units = "3";
Models.Name = "BMW";
Models.Description = "Luxury Car";
PCs.Price = "3000";
PCs.Units = "20";
```

Note that the values will be changing at runtime, and this will need to be updated when sending out data.
I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction here.

EDIT

Looks like this may not be viable.

Is there a way I can store a list of objects, where these objects point to my property/field so that i can retrieve its value? Of course assume that these class instances will be created only once, and I could register the class property/field in my output class. Then the output class can iterate over this list, retrieve the value of the object to which it points to, and then send the required data out?

e.g.

```
class OutputData
{
  Dictionary<string,object> OutputDataList = new Dictionary<string,object>();

  public void RegisterData(string displayName, ref object dataField)
  {
    OutputDataList.Add(displayName,dataField);
  }

  //iterate over OutputDataList and get the value of the property/field it points to
}
```

Comment: So, you want to iterate through all objects in memory and get their property values using reflection, right? I don't know any way to do that. I think you have to add them to some kind of global collection. You could add the objects to a global static collection in the constructor of every object, I guess. But then you'd have to delete them from the collection when the objects are destroyed or you'd have a memory leak.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I was hoping to avoid the whole register each property in a global class type approach, or even just picking them at design time - it enforces the need for classes to be dependant on each other. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of these objects exist for the lifetime of the application and you just need to keep track of all of them you could do that in the constructor for each class, something like:

```
public class Tracker
{
  public static List<object> AllObjects = new List<object>();
}

public class ClassA
{
   public ClassA()
   {
      Tracker.AllObjects.Add(this);
   }
   ...
}
```

That way you'd only need to modify the classes you want to track and the instances will get tracked in the overall list.  For the problem of which fields to track you can either use reflection or you can store something more interesting in all objects, maybe a `Func<List<string>>` which returns all the values of interest.

The add line would then be:

```
      Tracker.AllObjects.Add(() => 
          { 
            yield return "Name:" + this.Name; 
            yield return "Description:" + this.Description;
          });
```

You can then do:

```
var ouputLines = Tracker.AllObjects.SelectMany(o => o());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this looks like these are fields of *something*:

```
public ClassA Cars = new ClassA();
public ClassB Models = new ClassB();
public ClassA PCs = new ClassA();
```

So lets be explicit about that:

```
public class Something {
    public ClassA Cars = new ClassA();
    public ClassB Models = new ClassB();
    public ClassA PCs = new ClassA();
}
```

So assuming those are fields in something, a quick pass with reflection will find them.  So far, so good.

What you need to understand though is that the name of the field (e.g. "Cars") is not associated with the instance of the variable- it is associated with the instance of the class that contains that field, in this case some `Something`.

To understand why, imagine this code:

```
var a = new Something();
var b = new Something();
b.PCs = a.Cars;
```

Now we have a variable of type ClassA that is stored in a.Cars *and* b.PCs.  Which label would you use?

You need to have a dictionary of these things, or otherwise constrain what they are called.  Something like this would do:

```
public Dictionary<String, Object> myStuff = new Dictionary<String, Object> { { "Cars", new ClassA() }, { "Models", new ClassB() }, { "PCs", new ClassA() } };

// then, to get the field names and values

var someObject = myStuff["PCs"];
foreach (var fi in someObject.GetType().GetFields()) {
    var fieldName = fi.Name;
    var fieldValue = fi.GetValue(someObject);
    // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this is essentially what im trying to do. Note that in my real-world example there are multiple `Something` classes, and i would need a global static dictionary to store all these objects - hence i have my `RegisterData()` method - i would be calling this method after class instantiation to register my specific properties i need to output.